# External filter search any number fail in datastage, Expected operator name, got: "[", line 134; text: pxbridge

Tags: unix, hive, etl, datastage

I've try to check if there are some row for nama_lngkp that contain any number using external filter. Below is the sample of the data

id nama_lngkp flag_nama
1  brook
2  jane2
3  k4ne
4  bruce

if the nama_lngkp contain any number/digit the flag_nama will be inserted by "1"

Below the filter command that inputted in external filter
"grep nama_lgkp like *\d*;"

Then when job is run, it failed show warning below:

```
-Orientation link
main_program: Syntax error: Expected operator name, got: "[", line 134; text: pxbridge
main_program: Syntax error: Expected operator name, got: "[", line 134; text: pxbridge
-Orientation link
-XMLProperties '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-16\'?><Properties version=\'1.1\'><Common><Context type=\'int\'>1</Context><Variant type=\'string\'>1.0</Variant><DescriptorVersion type=\'string\'>1.0</DescriptorVersion><PartitionType type=\'int\'>-1</PartitionType><RCP type=\'int\'>0</RCP></Common><Connection><URL modified=\'1\' type=\'string\'><![CDATA[jdbc:ibm:hive://10.0.37.158:10000]]></URL><Username modified=\'1\' type=\'string\'><![CDATA[admin]]></Username><Password modified=\'1\' type=\'protectedstring\'><![CDATA[{iisenc}AnISx4OskLz0qQ2+Fl4jvw==]]></Password><Attributes modified=\'1\' type=\'string\'><![CDATA[]]></Attributes></Connection><Usage><ReadMode type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></ReadMode><GenerateSQL type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[1]]></GenerateSQL><TableName modified=\'1\' type=\'string\'><![CDATA[test_etl.dukcapil_awal]]></TableName><EnableQuotedIDs modified=\'1\' type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></EnableQuotedIDs><SQL><EnablePartitionedReads collapsed=\'1\' type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></EnablePartitionedReads></SQL><Transaction collapsed=\'1\'><RecordCount type=\'int\'><![CDATA[2000]]></RecordCount><IsolationLevel type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></IsolationLevel><AutocommitMode type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></AutocommitMode><EndOfWave type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></EndOfWave><BeginEnd collapsed=\'1\' type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></BeginEnd></Transaction><Session><ArraySize type=\'int\'><![CDATA[1]]></ArraySize><FetchSize type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></FetchSize><ReportSchemaMismatch type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></ReportSchemaMismatch><DefaultLengthForColumns modified=\'1\' type=\'int\'><![CDATA[1000]]></DefaultLengthForColumns><DefaultLengthForLongColumns type=\'int\'><![CDATA[20000]]></DefaultLengthForLongColumns><GenerateAllColumnsAsUnicode type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></GenerateAllColumnsAsUnicode><CharacterSetForNonUnicodeColumns collapsed=\'1\' type=\'int\'><![CDATA[0]]></CharacterSetForNonUnicodeColumns><KeepConductorConnectionAlive type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[1]]></KeepConductorConnectionAlive></Session><HiveParameters collapsed=\'1\' type=\'string\'><![CDATA[]]><FailOnError type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></FailOnError></HiveParameters><BeforeAfter collapsed=\'1\' type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></BeforeAfter><Java><ConnectorClasspath type=\'string\'><![CDATA[$(DSHOME)/../DSComponents/bin/HiveConnector.jar;$(DSHOME);]]></ConnectorClasspath><Classpath type=\'string\'><![CDATA[$(DSHOME)/../../ASBNode/lib/java/iis-shared.jar;]]></Classpath><HeapSize type=\'int\'><![CDATA[256]]></HeapSize><ConnectorOtherOptions type=\'string\'><![CDATA[-Dcom.ibm.is.cc.options=noisfjars]]></ConnectorOtherOptions></Java><LimitRows collapsed=\'1\' type=\'bool\'><![CDATA[0]]></LimitRows></Usage></Properties >'
-connector '{
   variant=\'1.0\', 
   library="java:com/ibm/is/cc/hive/HiveConnectorLibrary,$(DSHOME)/../DSComponents/bin/HiveConnector.jar;$(DSHOME)", 
   version=1.0, 
   variantlist=\'V1;1.0::"java:com/ibm/is/cc/hive/HiveConnectorLibrary,$(DSHOME)/../DSComponents/bin/HiveConnector.jar;$(DSHOME)"\', 
   versionlist=\'1.0\', 
   name=HiveConnector
}'
-source 0 '{
      DSIsKey={id=1}, 
      DSSQLType={id=-5, prop_name=12, kab_name=12, kec_name=12, kel_name=12, no_prop=12, no_kab=12, no_kec=12, no_kel=12, no_rt=12, no_rw=12, no_kk=12, nik=12, nama_lgkp=12, jenis_klmin=12, stat_hbkel=12, tgl_lhr=12, tmpt_lhr=12, pddk_akh=12, status_kawin=12, nama_lgkp_ibu=12, alamat=12, jenis_pkrjn=12, no_akta_lhr=12, agama=12, objectkey=12, robotname=12, lastupdated=12, auth_key=12, status=4, status_namaibu=4, created_at=4, updated_at=4}, 
      DSSQLPrecision={prop_name=225, kab_name=2147483647, kec_name=2147483647, kel_name=2147483647, no_prop=2, no_kab=2, no_kec=2, no_kel=4, no_rt=2147483647, no_rw=2147483647, no_kk=2147483647, nik=16, nama_lgkp=225, jenis_klmin=2147483647, stat_hbkel=225, tgl_lhr=2147483647, tmpt_lhr=2147483647, pddk_akh=2147483647, status_kawin=2147483647, nama_lgkp_ibu=225, alamat=2147483647, jenis_pkrjn=2147483647, no_akta_lhr=2147483647, agama=2147483647, objectkey=2147483647, robotname=2147483647, lastupdated=2147483647, auth_key=2147483647}, 
      DSNativeType={id=\'bigint\', kab_name=\'string\', kec_name=\'string\', kel_name=\'string\', no_rt=\'string\', no_rw=\'string\', no_kk=\'string\', jenis_klmin=\'string\', tgl_lhr=\'string\', tmpt_lhr=\'string\', pddk_akh=\'string\', status_kawin=\'string\', alamat=\'string\', jenis_pkrjn=\'string\', no_akta_lhr=\'string\', agama=\'string\', objectkey=\'string\', robotname=\'string\', lastupdated=\'string\', auth_key=\'string\', status=\'int\', status_namaibu=\'int\', created_at=\'int\', updated_at=\'int\'}, 
      DSSchema=\'record
         (
           id\:nullable int64\;
           prop_name\:nullable ustring\[max\=225\]\;
           kab_name\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           kec_name\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           kel_name\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           no_prop\:nullable ustring\[max\=2\]\;
           no_kab\:nullable ustring\[max\=2\]\;
           no_kec\:nullable ustring\[max\=2\]\;
           no_kel\:nullable ustring\[max\=4\]\;
           no_rt\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           no_rw\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           no_kk\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           nik\:nullable ustring\[max\=16\]\;
           nama_lgkp\:nullable ustring\[max\=225\]\;
           jenis_klmin\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           stat_hbkel\:nullable ustring\[max\=225\]\;
           tgl_lhr\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           tmpt_lhr\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           pddk_akh\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           status_kawin\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           nama_lgkp_ibu\:nullable ustring\[max\=225\]\;
           alamat\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           jenis_pkrjn\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           no_akta_lhr\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           agama\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           objectkey\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           robotname\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           lastupdated\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           auth_key\:nullable ustring\[\]\;
           status\:nullable int32\;
           status_namaibu\:nullable int32\;
           created_at\:nullable int32\;
           updated_at\:nullable int32\;
         )\'
}'
[ident('dukcapil_awal'); jobmon_ident('dukcapil_awal')]
0> [modify(keep id,prop_name,kab_name,kec_name,kel_name,no_prop,no_kab,no_kec,no_kel,no_rt,no_rw,no_kk,nik,nama_lgkp,jenis_klmin,stat_hbkel,tgl_lhr,tmpt_lhr,pddk_akh,status_kawin,nama_lgkp_ibu,alamat,jenis_pkrjn,no_akta_lhr,agama,objectkey,robotname,lastupdated,auth_key,status,status_namaibu,created_at,updated_at;id:nullable int64=id;prop_name:nullable ustring[max=225]=prop_name;kab_name:nullable ustring=kab_name;kec_name:nullable ustring=kec_name;kel_name:nullable ustring=kel_name;no_prop:nullable ustring[max=2]=no_prop;no_kab:nullable ustring[max=2]=no_kab;no_kec:nullable ustring[max=2]=no_kec;no_kel:nullable ustring[max=4]=no_kel;no_rt:nullable ustring=no_rt;no_rw:nullable ustring=no_rw;no_kk:nullable ustring=no_kk;nik:nullable ustring[max=16]=nik;nama_lgkp:nullable ustring[max=225]=nama_lgkp;jenis_klmin:nullable ustring=jenis_klmin;stat_hbkel:nullable ustring[max=225]=stat_hbkel;tgl_lhr:nullable ustring=tgl_lhr;tmpt_lhr:nullable ustring=tmpt_lhr;pddk_akh:nullable ustring=pddk_akh;status_kawin:nullable ustring=status_kawin;nama_lgkp_ibu:nullable ustring[max=225]=nama_lgkp_ibu;alamat:nullable ustring=alamat;jenis_pkrjn:nullable ustring=jenis_pkrjn;no_akta_lhr:nullable ustring=no_akta_lhr;agama:nullable ustring=agama;objectkey:nullable ustring=objectkey;robotname:nullable ustring=robotname;lastupdated:nullable ustring=lastupdated;auth_key:nullable ustring=auth_key;status:nullable int32=status;status_namaibu:nullable int32=status_namaibu;created_at:nullable int32=created_at;updated_at:nullable int32=updated_at;)] 'dukcapil_awal:data_dukcapil.v'
;
transform
-flag run
-name 'V0S1_Tabel_flag_tes_1_Transformer_1'
[ident('Transformer_1'); jobmon_ident('Transformer_1')]
0< [] 'dukcapil_awal:data_dukcapil.v'
0> [] 'Transformer_1:DSLink84.v'
;
export
-schema record {final_delim=end, delim=",", quote=double} ( id: nullable int64;  nama_lgkp: nullable ustring[max=225];  flag_nama: ustring[max=10]; )
-file 'D:\\coba1l.xls'
-overwrite
-rejects continue
[ident('Coba1'); jobmon_ident('Coba1')]
0< [] 'External_Filter_104:Case1.v'
;
tsort -key id -asc -nulls first -nonStable
[ident('External_Filter_104.DSLink84_Sort')]
0< [] 'Transformer_1:DSLink84.v'
0> [-pp] 'Transformer_1:DSLink84_Sort.v'
;
ordered
[ident('External_Filter_104.DSLink84_Part')]
0< [] 'Transformer_1:DSLink84_Sort.v'
0> [] 'Transformer_1:DSLink84_Sort_Part.v'
;
grep nama_lgkp like *\d*;
[
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any datastage user in here?  The documentation in ibm site is not clear enaough

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you add a designer image of your job ?